# MSMQ Configuration in global elements properties

Tags: mule, msmq

I am trying to run the sample example from Mule blog for MSMQ. When I setup MSMQ as global component "Test connection" says Test Connection failed. Error message-

> The connector and proxy versions do not match**. And also in Reason
>   mentioned org.mule.api.ConnectionException:The connector and proxy
>   versions do not match

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is working fine now. The exception occurred because of version problem in MSMQ connector and Anypoint Gateway service for windows. I have download the latest version of Gateway service for windows and installed. Then Test connection is Successfully connected.